# I am not able to submit the form and put the data in Database in a django website

Tags: html, jquery, django, post, django-forms

I am fairly new to jQuery, in fact just started learning and using it.
I went through some of the questions but none talks about the issue I am facing so here it goes.

I have created a website in django.

In it I basically make a invoice and put that data into a SQL Server database, and then fetch that data and render it to another html template and then print it from there.

Earlier I wasn't using a jQuery in the html. That time it worked all fine. now i decided that i will use the jQuery to append rows instead of having a fixed amount of rows.

When I started using that it started giving trouble. now my input tag that's set on submit is not submitting the form, or that's what I think is happening.

Can someone please help me out here?

The following contains my part of the view which is working on this, the html and the urls file.

**views.py**

```
def invoice(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    name_client = request.POST.get('client_name')
    address_client = request.POST.get('client_address')
    name_company = request.POST.get('company_name')
    address_company = request.POST.get('company_address')
    vessel_name = request.POST.get('vessel_name')
    po = request.POST.get('po')
    date = request.POST.get('date')

    item1 = request.POST.get('product1')
    cost1 = int(request.POST.get('cost1'))
    gst1 = int(request.POST.get('gst1'))        ########

    item2 = request.POST.get('product2',"")
    cost2 = int(request.POST.get('cost2',0))
    gst2 = int(request.POST.get('gst2',0))        ########

    item3 = request.POST.get('product3',"")
    cost3 = int(request.POST.get('cost3',0))
    gst3 = int(request.POST.get('gst3',0))        ########
    gst1 = gst1 / 100
    gst2 = gst2 / 100
    gst3 = gst3 / 100
    cost1 = (cost1 * gst1) + cost1
    cost2 = (cost1 * gst2) + cost2
    cost3 = (cost1 * gst3) + cost3
    total = cost3 + cost2 + cost1
    cursor.execute('select top 1 id from InvoiceBackup order by id desc')
    id = cursor.fetchall()
    id[0][0] += 1
    invoice_number = str(id[0][0]) + '/2021'
    data = (
        name_client, address_client, name_company,
        address_company, vessel_name,
        po, invoice_number, date, item1,
        gst1, cost1, item2,
        gst2, cost2, item3, gst3, cost3,
        total, 0, 0, 0, '',
        datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('asia/kolkata')))
    print(data)
    sql = 'insert into InvoiceBackup values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.execute('select top 1 * from InvoiceBackup order by id desc')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return render(request, 'invoice_template.html', {'data': data})
else:
    return render(request, 'invoice.html',
                  {'company': company_name(), 'product': product_name(), 'clients': client_name()})

def invoiceview(request):
    cursor.execute('select top 1 * from InvoiceBackup order by id desc')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return render(request, 'print_template.html', {'data': data})

def invoiceprint(request):
    url = '127.0.0.1:8000/invoiceview'
    output = pdfkit.from_url(url, output_path=False)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
    response.write(output)
    return response
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from .views import *
urlpatterns = [
    path('', test , name='test'),
    path('invoice/',invoice),
    path('invoiceview',invoiceview),
    path('printinvoice/',invoiceprint),
]
```

**invoice.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block table_name %}Invoice{% endblock %}
{% block table_view %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="1" class="center table-responsive table table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left:418px" id="mans">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="6">INVOICE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED TO</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center"><!--input class="center" style="width:100%" type="text" list="l1" name="client_name" placeholder="Client Name"-->
                    <input list="show" type="text" class="center" style="width:100%" name="client_name">
                    <datalist id="show">
                        {% for client in clients %}
                        <option value="{{ client.first_name }}"></option>
              <!--<input type="hidden" value="{{client.client_id}}" name="client_name">-->
                        {% endfor %}
                    </datalist>
                    <br><br><textarea type="text" name="client_address" placeholder="Address" style="width:100%" rows="3"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED FROM</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center"><input type="text" name="company_name" style="width:100%" placeholder="Company Name"><br>
                    <br><textarea type="text" name="company_address" placeholder="Address" rows="3" style="width:100%"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">VESSEL NAME</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center"><input name="vessel_name" style="width:70%" type="text" placeholder="Vessel Name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">PO NUMBER</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center"><input type="text" name="po" style="width:70%" placeholder="PO number"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICE NUMBER</th>
                <td><input name="invoice_number" type="text" placeholder="#/2021" disabled></td>
                <th>DATE</th>
                <td colspan="" class="center"><input type="date" name="date"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER">
                <th>S. NO.</th>
                <th COLSPAN="2">PARTICULARS</th>
                <th COLSPAN="1">GST</th>
                <th colspan="2">TOTAL AMOUNT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER">
                <td class="center">1</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class='center'><input type="text" name="product1" placeholder="Name of product"></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="gst1" placeholder="gst"></td>
                <td COLSPAN="2"><input name="cost1" type="number" placeholder="cost"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- <tr CLASS="CENTER">
                <td class="center">2</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center"><input type="text" name="product2" placeholder="Name of product"></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="gst2" placeholder="gst"></td>
                <td COLSPAN="2"><input name="cost2" type="number" placeholder="cost"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER">
                <td class="center">3</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center"><input type="text" name="product3" placeholder="Name of product"></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="gst3" placeholder="gst"></td>
                <td COLSPAN="2"><input name="cost3" type="number" placeholder="cost"></td>
            </tr> -->
        </table>
        <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg add-row">add row</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"></center>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
{% block script %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let lineNo = 2;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".add-row").click(function () {
                new_line = "<tr CLASS='CENTER'>   <td class='center'>"+lineNo
                    +"</td><td COLSPAN='2' class='center'><input type='text' name='product"+lineNo
                        +"' placeholder='Name of product'></td><td><input type='number' name='gst"+lineNo
                            +"' placeholder='gst'></td><td COLSPAN='2'><input name='cost"+lineNo
                                +"' type='number' placeholder='cost'></td></tr>";

                tableBody = $("#mans");
                tableBody.append(new_line);
                lineNo++;
            });
        }); 
</script>
{% endblock script%}
```

**invoice_template.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <table border="1" align="center" class="center" width="60%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr><th colspan="6"><center><img src="{% static 'assets/img/logo.png' %}" style="width:400px" alt="Oceanbrave Shipping Pvt. Ltd."></center>
</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="7">INVOICE</th>
                </tr>
            {% for i in data %}
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED TO</th>
                <td colspan="4" align="center" class="center"><br>{{i.1}}
                    <br>{{i.2}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED FROM</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center" align="center"><br>{{i.3}}
                    <br>{{i.4}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">VESSEL NAME</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center" align="center">{{i.5}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">PO NUMBER</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center" align="center">{{i.6}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICE NUMBER</th>
                <td>{{i.7}}</td>
                <th>DATE</th>
                <td colspan="" class="center">{{i.8}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <th>S. NO.</th>
                <th COLSPAN="2">PARTICULARS</th>
                <th COLSPAN="1">GST</th>
                <th colspan="2">TOTAL AMOUNT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <td class="center">1</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center">{{i.9}}</td>
                <td>{{i.10}}</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2">{{i.11}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <td class="center">2</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center">{{i.12}}</td>
                <td>{{i.13}}</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2">{{i.14}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <td class="center">3</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center">{{i.15}}</td>
                <td>{{i.16}}</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2">{{i.17}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <th colspan="3" >GRAND TOTAL</th>
                <TD colspan="3" >{{i.18}}</TD>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center"><th colspan="6">BANK DETAILS</th> </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Name</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Account Name</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Account Number</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Account Type</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Branch Name</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Address</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">IFSC Code</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Swift Code</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="left">
                    Note<br>
                    1.&nbsp Please credit invoiced amount to bank account without any bank charges/deductions.<br>
                    2.&nbsp Please make the payment within 5 days from invoice date.<br>
                    3.&nbsp Interest of 1.5% per month on pro-rate basis will be charged on delayed duration.<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><!--&nbsp-->
                    <b style="white-space:pre">&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9Finance Executive</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <TR hidden>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
            </TR>

            <TR hidden>
                <TD>D</TD>
                <TD>SLJFSDMS</TD>
                <TD>SDKFLSNK</TD>
                <TD>S.KFKMML</TD>
                <TD>SDLFKJSL</TD>
                <td>dkufuhsk</td>
            </TR>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </form>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/printinvoice" onclick="window.print()">Print</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/invoice">Back</a>
</body>
</html>
<!--position relative-->
```

**print_template.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <table border="1" align="center" class="center" width="60%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr><th colspan="7"><center><img src="{% static 'assets/img/logo.png' %}" style="width:400px" alt="Oceanbrave Shipping Pvt. Ltd."></center>
</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="7">INVOICE</th>
                </tr>
            {% for i in data %}
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED TO</th>
                <td colspan="4" align="center" class="center"><br>{{i.1}}
                    <br>{{i.2}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED FROM</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center" align="center"><br>{{i.3}}
                    <br>{{i.4}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">VESSEL NAME</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center" align="center">{{i.5}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">PO NUMBER</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center" align="center">{{i.6}}</td>

            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICE NUMBER</th>
                <td>{{i.7}}</td>
                <th colspan="1">DATE</th>
                <td colspan="2" class="center">{{i.8}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <th>S. NO.</th>
                <th COLSPAN="2">PARTICULARS</th>
                <th COLSPAN="1">IGST(%)</th>
                <th COLSPAN="1">CGST(%)</th>
                <th colspan="1" >Units </th>
                <th colspan="1">TOTAL AMOUNT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <td class="center">1</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center">{{i.9}}</td>
                <td>{{i.10}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td COLSPAN="2">{{i.11}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <td class="center">2</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center">{{i.12}}</td>
                <td>{{i.13}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td COLSPAN="2">{{i.14}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER" align="center">
                <td class="center">3</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class="center">{{i.15}}</td>
                <td>{{i.16}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td COLSPAN="2">{{i.17}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <th colspan="3" >GRAND TOTAL</th>
                <TD colspan="4" >{{i.18}}</TD>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center"><th colspan="7">BANK DETAILS</th> </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Name</td>
                <td colspan="4">HDFC bank Ltd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Account Name</td>
                <td colspan="7">Oceanbrave Shipping Pvt Ltd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Account Number</td>
                <td colspan="7">50200009299268</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Account Type</td>
                <td colspan="7">EEFC USD Account</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Branch Name</td>
                <td colspan="7">Seawoods, Navi Mumbai</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Bank Address</td>
                <td colspan="7">Giriraj Co-op HSG, Shop No. 10/11/12, Sector-48, Sewoods, Navi Mumbai - 400706</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">IFSC Code</td>
                <td colspan="7">HDFC0001028</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3">Swift Code</td>
                <td colspan="7">HDFCINBBXXX</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="left">
                    Note<br>
                    1.&nbsp Please credit invoiced amount to bank account without any bank charges/deductions.<br>
                    2.&nbsp Please make the payment within 5 days from invoice date.<br>
                    3.&nbsp Interest of 1.5% per month on pro-rate basis will be charged on delayed duration.<!--&nbsp-->
                    <img src="{% static 'assets/img/stamp.png' %}" align="right" style="width:" alt="Oceanbrave Shipping Pvt. Ltd. Stamp">
                    <b style="white-space:pre">&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9&#9Finance Executive</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <TR hidden>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD></TD>
            </TR>

            <TR hidden>
                <TD>D</TD>
                <TD>SLJFSDMS</TD>
                <TD>SDKFLSNK</TD>
                <TD>S.KFKMML</TD>
                <TD>SDLFKJSL</TD>
                <td>dkufuhsk</td>
            </TR>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<!--position relative-->
```

When I am not using the jQuery all of this works fine, but now when I applied jQuery, it's not working.

Can someone please help me make this work?

Comment: You should consider using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), [DRF (Django Rest Framework)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and, conveniently, [DRF DataTables](https://django-rest-framework-datatables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - this will solve your use case instead of trying to build the tables yourself.

Comment: @Daniel The thing is I have completed this project and only this part is giving problem. There are many other pages and tables and cant exactly make these changes for everything right now. But i will surely apply these things from next time on. For now can this be fixed in the current method that i am using?